# Unable to run X11 (graphical) programs from atd

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to schedule the execution of a shell-script with the Linux tool "at".
The shell script (video.sh) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/vlc /home/x/video.mkv
```

The "at" command:

```
at -f /home/x/video.sh -t 201411052225
```

When the time arrives, nothing happens.

I can execute the shell-script just fine via console or by rightclicking - Execute. VLC starts like it is supposed to. If I change the script to e.g. something simple like

```
#!/bin/sh
touch something.txt
```

it works just fine.

Any ideas, why "at" will not properly execute a script that starts a graphical program? How can I make it work?

Comment: This script is supposed to play a video? Have you set the DISPLAY environment variable?

Comment: maybe vlc's trying to open a window, which won't do anything when it's run as a cron job with no console available?

Comment: Yes, the script should play a video, but even if the script is as simple as ´#!/bin/sh /usr/bin/vlc´ - meaning it should just start VLC without playing a video - it will not work. VLC does not start.

Comment: VLC is a graphical program even if it's started with no options. I suspect you'll find no X program will work.

Comment: The title, by the way, was very misleading. `touch` is, itself, a external program, separate from the shell, that you were proving that atd *could* in fact start. Your problem was that it couldn't run _graphical_ programs, not that it could run no programs at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are right, I was not very precise in my descriptions. Your correction and help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run an X command (a graphical program) at a scheduled time. This will be extremely difficult, and quite fragile, because the script won't have access to the X server.

At the very least, you will need to set `DISPLAY` to the right value, but even then, I suspect you will have issues with authorisation to use the X screen.

Try setting it to `:0.0` and see if that works. But if you're logged out, or the screensaver's on, or any number of other things...

(Also, redirect vlc's stdout and stderr to a file so that you can see what went wrong.)

Your best bet might be to try something like [xuserrun](https://github.com/rephorm/xuserrun).

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing the DISPLAY setting actually did the trick. I will do some thorough testing, how stable this solution is.

Comment: @bs-, keep in mind that one aspect of fragility is compatibility across security settings. Subsystems such as XAuthority exist specifically to prevent software without the right tokens (passed via environment variable and/or home directory) from connecting to an X server. If your distro doesn't use those security measures now, it may implement them in the future.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, This will be implemented on Raspberry Pis, running Arch Linux. Once everything is running smoothly, there will be no changes to the OS. The RPis are only there to receive commands from a remote server to show videos/pictures/websites.

Comment: @bs-, ahh -- that explains why it works. I actually was a bit surprised that you had a distribution that didn't enforce xauth out-of-the-box.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sorry for my sloppy explaining again: In fact, I have not tried this on the Raspy yet, but only on my Laptop running Debian Testing. I will try it on the RPi tomorrow and report back, if it also works there.

Comment: @bs- you should also think about using `omxplayer` instead of VLC if this is on Raspbian. It does something clever or naughty or both to be able to play full screen video even if X isn't running. It might be a more stable solution.

Comment: @chiastic-security, thank you - that was already planned because omxplayer supports the RPi's graphics way better than VLC. I just used VLC in my tests because I was doing them on my Debian Laptop which does not have omxplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `atd` is not running. You have to start the `atd` daemon before (and to set DISPLAY variable like chiastic-security said) ;)

You can test if `atd` is running with

```
pidof atd &>/dev/null && echo 'ATD started' || echo >&2 'ATD not started
```

Your vlc command should be :

```
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/vlc /home/x/video.mkv
```

(Default display)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but atd is indeed running. at will execute simple scripts like "touch somefile" or "echo something" just fine.

Comment: I changed the command and it worked, VLC now starts the video. Thank you very much!